# VB.NET - Is there a way to get file info from a file on a subversion repository? (Toriose svn)

Tags: vb.net, svn, tortoisesvn

I have a utility that checks various file info (size, date, location, etc) against a manifest to see that it all matches. Would anyone know if there's a way to get the last write date of a file in a svn repository, using VB.NET. The equivalent of using FileInfo.LastWriteDate.

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can call svn from the command line with the appropiate parameters to get this information. If that is possible, you can write a class which does that for a given file.

Other than that, there might be some library out there which does this and more things, but if what you asked for is the only thing you need from svn, using a library might be overkill